# Can't install Gphpedit

Tags: 12.04, php, editor

Why can I not install Gphpedit? I get these errors:

```
Failed to fetch //http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_1.8.1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Failed to fetch //http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit/libwebkitgtk-1.0-common_1.8.1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Failed to fetch //http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_1.8.1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt its because of software source server problem, you can try to choose server for your country by opening software sources and changing Download from drop down.

now on a terminal type

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gphpedit

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install an outdated package that is not available anymore.

Resynchronize the package index files, for example by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

from the command line and try again.